# add index of values in between elements in a string

Tags: python

For example:

```
input: "Orange"
output: "O0r1a2n3g4e5"
```

I know I will have to convert the string to a list so I can iterate and append the index numbers, but I don't know how to do that in code.

Answer (score 1):

```
''.join([f'{letter}{index}' for index, letter in enumerate(input)])
```